# Is there a way to convert nulls to blanks in a date data type column in PowerBI/Power Query?

Tags: null, powerbi, powerquery

I'm utilizing a combined SharePoint list into a single merged table in power BI. There are three columns related to resting dates for various diseases: [TestDate1], [TestDate2], [TestDate3].

I have this logic in a custom column:

```
if [TestDate1] <= [TestDate2] then [TestDate1] else if [TestDate1] <= [TestDate3] then [TestDate1] else if [TestDate2] <= [TestDate1] then [TestDate2] else if [TestDate2] <= [TestDate3] then [TestDate2] else if [TestDate3] <= [TestDate1] then [TestDate3] else if [TestDate3] <= [TestDate2] then [TestDate3] else ""
```

However, all of the TestDates are *null*. This is causing an error in the column because nulls cannot be used in a logical function in PowerQuery (from my understanding), so is there a way I can test this logic to see if it would produce the expected result?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could explicitly test for nulls in your formula such as

```
= if [TestDate1] = null then XXX else YYY
```

but your best bet might be to wrap the whole thing in **try** .. **otherwise** in case an error is returned

```
= try if a then b else c otherwise ZZZ
```

For your code:

```
= try if [TestDate1] <= [TestDate2] then [TestDate1] else if [TestDate1] <= [TestDate3] then [TestDate1] else if [TestDate2] <= [TestDate1] then [TestDate2] else if [TestDate2] <= [TestDate3] then [TestDate2] else if [TestDate3] <= [TestDate1] then [TestDate3] else if [TestDate3] <= [TestDate2] then [TestDate3] else "" otherwise ZZZZ
```

where ZZZ is the thing you'd like to return  (like null or [TestDate1] or "") in place of returning an error

Comment: Hey appreciate the response, ended up just adjusting all the nulls to a date in year 2200 and than doing the comparison of dates to that. Then created a calculated column and converted returns that had year 2200 to blank values. Bit of a workaround but produced the expected result.
Thanks again!