# Power Query incorporate null into equation

Tags: excel-formula, formatting, powerquery

I have 2 columns within power query, one as a helper column that contains numbers in each cell and acts kind of as a back up hwne the next column is empty. The other column contains values and the mentioned empty cells. I wish to perform calculations using these columns and so have formatted these to be as Decimal Number. This causes the empty cells to be returned as `null` which is fine although I can't get power query to recognise these when creating a custom column. I wish to create an if statement that if the second column is `null` then the value from the helper column is returned instead.

Testing this in another column using `= if [Custom.3] = "null"` just returns all values as False so clearly null can't be recognised.

Similarly I am unable to replace error to "" because it has to be a numerical value.

How can I get power query to recognise when a value is not present?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**= if [Custom.3] = "null"** just tests for a text word of length 4 letters, null

To test for an actual null, use **= if [Custom.3] = null**

See sample code I provided to your other question at [convert null to blanks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66550114/is-there-a-way-to-convert-nulls-to-blanks-in-a-date-data-type-column-in-powerbi/66550545#66550545)

Note: if it is not a null (are you sure?) then try a line feed **#(lf)**